# Regex (?J) mode modifier in Python Regex or equival ability for named capture group from different patterns

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to capture from two different pattern sequences using a named capture group. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58618907/how-to-capture-text-on-either-side-of-a-pattern-into-a-named-capture-group) solves the problem in PCRE using the mode modifier `(?J)`, and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39029801/how-to-use-a-named-regex-capture-before-or-after-a-non-capturing-group-when-name) solves a related problem in Python that I haven't succeeded at applying to my use case.

Example test strings:

```
abc-CAPTUREME-xyz-abcdef
abc-xyz-CAPTUREME-abcdef
```

Desired output:

```
CAPTUREME
CAPTUREME
```

`CAPTUREME` appears on either the left or right of the `xyz` sequence. My initial failed attempt at a regex looked like this:

```
r'abc-(xyz-(?P<cap>\w+)|(?P<cap>\w+)-xyz)-abcdef'
```

But in Python regexes that yields an error `(?P<cap> A subpattern name must be unique)` and python doesn't support the `(?J)` modifier that was used in the first answer above to solve the problem.

With a single capture group I can capture `CAPTUREME-xyz` or `xyz-CAPTUREME`, but I can't reproduce the example in the 2nd stack overflow article linked above using lookarounds. Every attempt to replicate the 2nd stack overflow article simply doesn't match my string and there are too many differences for me to piece together what's happening.

```
r'abc-(?P<cap>(xyz-)\w+|\w+(-xyz))-abcdef'
```

https://regex101.com/r/NeWrDe/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the second article, you could write the pattern as:

```
(?P<cap>(?<=abc-xyz-)\w+|\w+(?=-xyz-abcdef))
```

**Explanation**

- `(?P<cap>` Named group *cap*

  - `(?<=abc-xyz-)\w+` Match 1+ word characters, asserting abc-xyz- to the left
  - `|` Or
  - `\w+(?=-xyz-abcdef)` Match 1+ word characters, asserting -xyz-abcdef to the right
- `)` Close group *cap*

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nbH3fo/1)

---

Another option in Python could be using a conditional and a capture group:

```
abc-(xyz-)?(?P<cap>\w+)-(?(1)|xyz-)abcdef
```

**Explanation**

- `abc-(xyz-)?` Match `abc-` and optionally capture `xyz-` in group 1
- `(?P<cap>\w+)` Named group *cap*, match 1+ word characters
- `-` Match literally
- `(?(1)|xyz-)` If group 1 is not present, match `xyz-`
- `abcdef` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zTmygt/1)

Comment: The second solution works and is the most general purpose, the first solution requires that the rest of the match string be trivial text which may not be the case in practice. Thanks for this! The conditional capture group was quite new to me, that's a nice trick, and not one I came across when searching for this, so hopefully it gets found by others.